# Find class name

Tags: javascript

How can I find class from

```
<div class="sidebar-toggle sidebar-collapse" id="sidebar-collapse">
    <i class="ace-icon fa fa-angle-double-right" data-icon2="ace-icon fa fa-angle-double-right" data-icon1="ace-icon fa fa-angle-double-left"></i>
</div>
```

I want to find `ace-icon fa fa-angle-double-right`
I have tried this

```
    var sidebar_collapse = document.getElementById("sidebar-collapse");
    $(sidebar_collapse).on('click', function () {
        var angel_double_right = $(sidebar_collapse).find('.ace-icon fa fa-angle-double-right');
        if (angel_double_right) {
            alert("yeah has class");
            $(ticksign).css('display', 'none');
        }
    });
```

But not working. It alert every time

Comment: `if (angel_double_right.length)`. jQuery objects are always *truthy*, even if they don't contain any elements.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there an “exists” function for jQuery?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31044/is-there-an-exists-function-for-jquery)

Comment: Also, your selector should be `'.ace-icon.fa.fa-angle-double-right'` (there was an answer with this but it's been removed)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Access the child and then get the class name:

```js
document.write(JSON.stringify(document.getElementById("sidebar-collapse").children[0].className));
```

```html
<div class="sidebar-toggle sidebar-collapse" id="sidebar-collapse">
    <i class="ace-icon fa fa-angle-double-right" data-icon2="ace-icon fa fa-angle-double-right" data-icon1="ace-icon fa fa-angle-double-left"></i>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

`.find()` returns a jQuery object, which evaluates to `true` every time. So your `if` condition will always be true. If you need to check if any elements actually matched the selector:

```
if (angel_double_right.length) {
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$("sidebar-collapse").on('click', function () {
    var angel_double_right = $(this).find('.ace-icon.fa.fa-angle-double-right');
    if (angel_double_right.length>0) {
        alert("yeah has class");
        $(ticksign).css('display', 'none');
    }
});
```

Comment: if one element has more than one class name than write as below     .ace-icon.fa.fa-angle-double-right